# Can Button be a return type in Java?

Tags: java

Which of the following is not a return type in Java: boolean, void, public or Button?
I think a Button CAN be a return type (return types aren't solely primitives, right?). Public cannot be a return type, because it is an access modifier, is it correct?
Thank you for clarifying this for me.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Please read Oracle java tutorial (or any other tutorial) and yes public is an access modifier

Comment: Public and public are not the same.

Comment: No, I found an online test and I am curious if my judgement is correct because I found Button as an answer but I don't trust the source. I'm thinking there may be methods that need to return a certain object (a visual component in this case). So I think it makes sense to have a Button or JButton returned. But public is not a return type, it's altogether a distinct category - access modifiers. Comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every type can be a return type in Java. Including `void`.

`public` is an access modifier, so it cannot be a return type.

Comment: Kocko: what about 'Public' ? Are you sure you didn't mean Void instead of void ?

Comment: `public void method() {}` has a return type of `void`. Lower-cased. So I am sure I meant `void`. What is `Public`? :)

Comment: Public is what the OP was talking about in his question, not public. void can be considered a return type, but it's rather a type indicating that nothing is returned. On the other hand ..
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html
might be a matter of semantics, but still .. :)

Comment: @Stultuske This is the OP's question: "Which of the following is not a return type in Java: boolean, void, public or Button?". Do you see any Public in there?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt did you also read:  Public cannot be a return type,
I missed that one indeed, though.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes of course. In the OP's further explanation (not his question), he capitalized Public because it started a sentence. Kocko rightfully answers the *question* of the OP.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt so where my second reply was wrong, the first still was correct.

Answer (score 2):

Every primitive type and every class can be a return type.
"public" cannot be a return type since it is a reserved keyword, but "Public" can.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's extremely bad to name your Class Public, but you can, in which case it is a valid return type.

Answer (score 1):

Of course Button or JButton can be a return type.
They are actual classes, meaning they will be the type of Object your method returns.

For instance: to create Buttons with a text and a text that will be printed when clicking upon them:

```
public JButton getButton(String text, String print){
  JButton result = new JButton(text);
  result.addActionListener(new ActionListern(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ClickEvent event){
      System.out.println(print);
    }
});
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any variable type can be a return type, that is primitive or object class.

public/private/protected are access modifiers as you said. These just specify which classes this method is view-able by.

Comment: actually, Public/Private/Protected are not access modifiers. public, private and protected are. Java is case sensititve, meaning that Public, even though it would be a bit of a strangely chosen name, won't cause any problems.

Comment: sorry, typo... corrected